# When LinkedList size is -1

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm facing this exception, in a java 1.7 project:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: -1
   at java.util.LinkedList.checkPositionIndex(LinkedList.java:558) ~[na:1.7.0_251]
   at java.util.LinkedList.listIterator(LinkedList.java:865) ~[na:1.7.0_251]
   at java.util.AbstractList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:299) ~[na:1.7.0_251]
   at java.util.AbstractSequentialList.iterator(AbstractSequentialList.java:239) ~[na:1.7.0_251]
   at com.project.exceptions.handlers.JsfExceptionHandler.handle(JsfExceptionHandler.java:74) ~[project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119) ~[jsf-impl-2.1.13-redhat-1.jar!/:2.1.13-redhat-1]
   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) ~[jsf-impl-2.1.13-redhat-1.jar!/:2.1.13-redhat-1]
   at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.render(FlowLifecycle.java:80) ~[spring-faces-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfView.render(JsfView.java:89) ~[spring-faces-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:296) ~[spring-webflow-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:207) ~[spring-webflow-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545) [spring-webflow-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:258) [spring-webflow-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
   ... 62 common frames omitted
```

but i can't figure out in which situation the size of a LinkedList could be -1, isn't suppose to be a positive number? Any suggestion?

Custom Exception Handler code (row 74 is the for)

```
    public class JsfExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandlerWrapper {
        ...
        @Override
        public void handle() throws FacesException {
            FacesContext fc = ContextUtils.getFacesContextInstance();
            for (Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> i = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
               ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and post your code... how are we supposed to help without knowing what you're doing? See [ask].

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't need someone to debug my code, I just need to know in which case the size of a LinkedList could be equal to -1, isn't suppose to be a positive number or at last zero? That's a generic question, because maybe I'm just missing something.

Comment: It's much more practical for you to show your code so we can figure out _why_ its returning -1, rather than us trying to guess every possible case in which it could happen. In this case, we may not be necessarily debugging your code, but we would hopefully be able to explain why you got -1 at least.

Comment: I have to agree it is not a matter of @Matteo's code, how can LinkedList.size be -1 is pretty straightforward a question.

Comment: as `LinkedList` is not thread-safe, could it be that your code removed simultaneously from different threads some items from the list?

Comment: It looks like you have a custom JsfExceptionHandler that is trying to iterate over some List when the IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown.  Consider debugging the Handler to monitor the state of the offending LinkedList.

Comment: Your're right, is even easier to understand if I should post the code, but I simply don't know it ^^ It's spring framework that is raising it, not my code, so I'm a in a sort of pre-debug phase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am able to reproduce the size of a `LinkedList` being -1 if I run this code couple of times:

```
         try {
            LinkedList<Integer> integers = new LinkedList<>();
            integers.add(1);
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1950);
                    integers.removeFirst();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).start();

            Thread.sleep(1950);
            integers.removeFirst();


            System.out.println(integers.size());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

As `LinkedList` is not thread-safe, trying to remove some elements from the `LinkedList` instance simultaneously from different threads might lead to the size being -1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I put MAX_INTEGER+1 item in the list, did I get the same result?

Comment: yes, you should get the same result if you run `integers.add(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1)`, but the code sample is not deterministic, so you have to run it multiple times to get -1. sometimes you get a `NoSuchElementException`.

Answer (score 1):

The only explanation that comes to mind is if the linked list is being passed over the wire and the sender explicitly sets its size as -1 in the payload.

Then the endpoint would try and possibly succeed in setting the size to -1 via reflection.

But is is a shot in the dark.

Comment: The `readObject` method does not set the `size` field explicitly.  Instead it uses the on-the-wire size for a `for` loop bound.  It is not possible for `size` in the materialized object to become -1 this way.  Check the code.